# How to add two values in tableview cell and displayed in label

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am new to IOS I had two view controller one for entering data in form based and another one, data entered in first view controller are saved in this controller.Below my screen shot for saved data there payable value i want to add and displayed in below total label.

Coding for tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.amountlbl.text = [device valueForKey:@"amount"];
    cell.currlbl.text = [device valueForKey:@"currency"];
    cell.typelbl.text = [device valueForKey:@"type"];
    cell.totlbl.text= [device valueForKey:@"total"];
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to do a little more studying. You are using insertNewObjectForEntityForName which means that every time you access the save method you are adding a new record to your table. You need to test for an existing record first using NSPredicate. You should also look at NSPredicate for how to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thank you  @Dominic